# How do I sort this list in Python, if my date is in a String?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, datetime

```
[{'date': '2010-04-01', 'people': 1047, 'hits': 4522}, {'date': '2010-04-03', 'people': 617, 'hits': 2582}, {'date': '2010-04-02', 'people': 736, 'hits': 3277}]
```

Suppose I have this list. How do I sort by "date", which is an item in the dictionary. But, "date" is a string...

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
.sort(key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x['date'], '%Y-%m-%d'))
```

Comment: this looks cool but i got "None" for an answer when i tried it!

Comment: Most `list` methods work in-place, instead of returning the list.

Comment: I like the flexibility of this answer. In my case, I had to resort to '%m/%d/%Y'.

Comment: Additional context on @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams comment:  when he says, "works in place", he's saying you do not need to set a variable.   You can simply run the code.

Answer (score 27):

Fortunately, ISO format dates, which seems to be what you have here, sort perfectly well *as strings*!  So you need nothing fancy:

```
import operator
yourlistofdicts.sort(key=operator.itemgetter('date'))
```

Answer (score 18):

Satoru.Logic's solution is clean and simple. But, per Alex's post, you don't need to manipulate the date string to get the sort order right...so lose the `.split('-')`

This code will suffice:

```
records.sort(key=lambda x:x['date'])
```

Comment: ...And once again the simplest, most Pythonic, and correct answer is hastily brushed aside when the asker is too hasty *sighs*.

Comment: Upvoted for simplicity, but definitely requires dates to be in YYYY-MM-DD format (which therefore sort similarly as strings).

Answer (score 4):

In python 2.6 you can use soerted w/operator.itemgetter.
Since date is YYYY-MM-DD it is sorted even though its a string cause its largest to smallest - i use that format all the time for this reason

```
>>> import operator
>>> l = [{'date': '2010-04-01','people': 1047, 'hits': 4522}, 
         {'date': '2010-04-03', 'people': 617, 'hits': 2582}, 
         {'date': '2010-04-02', 'people': 736, 'hits': 3277}]
>>> sorted( l, key = operator.itemgetter('date') )
[{'date': '2010-04-01', 'hits': 4522, 'people': 1047}, {'date': '2010-04-02', 'hits': 3277, 'people': 736}, {'date': '2010-04-03', 'hits': 2582, 'people': 617}]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
records = [
     {'date': '2010-04-01', 'people': 1047, 'hits': 4522}, 
     {'date': '2010-04-03', 'people': 617, 'hits': 2582}, 
     {'date': '2010-04-02', 'people': 736, 'hits': 3277}
     ]
records.sort(key=lambda x: x['date'].split('-'))
```

Comment: Note that this sort won't work if the dates aren't zero-filled. For, example 2-1 would come after 10-1, even though February comes before October.