# Sort list of month name strings in ascending order

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting, date

Can someone please guide how to sort list of months?

```
INPUT = ['August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December', 'January']

OUTPUT= ['January','August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
```

Comment: You can use the approach in the second answer here [Sort a list of dates by months](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32290801/sort-a-list-of-dates-by-month-in-python)

Comment: @MT756, actually the accepted answer in the link you shared is the best approach. They just need different format code.

Comment: @buran, right you could use %B as the format

Answer (score 9):

[`calendar.month_name`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.month_name) is an object that can be converted to a list of months in the correct sequence. You can sort by the index of each string in this list, assuming your input strings are well-formed:

```
>>> from calendar import month_name
>>> month_lookup = list(month_name)
>>> months = ['August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December', 'January']
>>> sorted(months, key=month_lookup.index)
['January', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
```

You can also use [`datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) and the `"%B"` format string which matches the full month name.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> months = ['August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December', 'January']
>>> sorted(months, key=lambda m: datetime.strptime(m, "%B"))
['January', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
```

Note that both solutions raise a `ValueError` on lists containing invalid month strings. The datetime version gives a clearer message.

Answer (score 1):

You can have the sort of months using this code:

```py
import datetime
months_dict = {}
for i in range(1,13):
    months_dict[datetime.date(2020, i, 1).strftime('%B').lower()] = i
print(months_dict)
# {'january': 0, 'february': 1, 'march': 2, 'april': 3, 'may': 4, 'june': 5, 'july': 6, 'august': 7, 'september': 8, 'october': 9, 'november': 10, 'december': 11}
```

And then you can sort your list using `sorted` function:

```py
months = ['August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December', 'January']
print(sorted(months, key=lambda x: months_dict[x.lower()]))
# ['January', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
```

Answer (score 0):

[Before:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fgqC.png)

|  | Month | Unit Cost | Unit Price | Cost | Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | April | 349.5117 | 404.5586 | 578.0353 | 670.268 |
| 1 | August | 312.0705 | 328.6801 | 513.1332 | 541.747 |
| 2 | December | 363.7626 | 376.0639 | 600.0729 | 619.8292 |
| 3 | February | 363.1559 | 416.4736 | 600.8566 | 690.7631 |
| 4 | January | 353.7365 | 411.386 | 576.6068 | 671.0083 |
| 5 | July | 324.0404 | 358.1196 | 522.9842 | 578.1788 |
| 6 | June | 384.2446 | 441.8092 | 634.0019 | 728.8003 |
| 7 | March | 354.2986 | 411.4245 | 584.3813 | 676.8101 |
| 8 | May | 380.1465 | 438.6138 | 619.3439 | 714.3145 |
| 9 | November | 339.0641 | 351.9415 | 556.4498 | 578.3473 |

```py
from calendar import month_name
month_lookup = list(month_name)
data_group.Month = sorted(data_group.Month, key=month_lookup.index)
```

[After:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYEcR.png)

|  | Month | Unit Cost | Unit Price | Cost | Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | January | 349.5117 | 404.5586 | 578.0353 | 670.268 |
| 1 | February | 312.0705 | 328.6801 | 513.1332 | 541.747 |
| 2 | March | 363.7626 | 376.0639 | 600.0729 | 619.8292 |
| 3 | April | 363.1559 | 416.4736 | 600.8566 | 690.7631 |
| 4 | May | 353.7365 | 411.386 | 576.6068 | 671.0083 |
| 5 | June | 324.0404 | 358.1196 | 522.9842 | 578.1788 |
| 6 | July | 384.2446 | 441.8092 | 634.0019 | 728.8003 |
| 7 | August | 354.2986 | 411.4245 | 584.3813 | 676.8101 |
| 8 | September | 380.1465 | 438.6138 | 619.3439 | 714.3145 |
| 9 | October | 339.0641 | 351.9415 | 556.4498 | 578.3473 |