How to sort a nested dictionary (having a list) in python?
I am stuck with nested dictionary sorting. How to sort the following dictionary in the chronological order?
{2024: {
  'Jul': ['Rate', 'Hours', 'Cost']
  'Jan': ['Rate', 'Hours', 'Cost'],
  'Feb': ['Rate', 'Hours', 'Cost'],
  'Mar': ['Rate', 'Hours', 'Cost'],
  'Apr': ['Rate', 'Hours', 'Cost'],
  'May': ['Rate', 'Hours', 'Cost'],
  'Jun': ['Rate', 'Hours', 'Cost']}}

The output should be as below:
{2024: {
  'Jan': ['Rate', 'Hours', 'Cost'],
  'Feb': ['Rate', 'Hours', 'Cost'],
  'Mar': ['Rate', 'Hours', 'Cost'],
  'Apr': ['Rate', 'Hours', 'Cost'],
  'May': ['Rate', 'Hours', 'Cost'],
  'Jun': ['Rate', 'Hours', 'Cost'],
  'Jul': ['Rate', 'Hours', 'Cost']}}

Through internet search I could only find one level of nesting.

I mean, dictionaries are technically ordered, but if you need sorting I'm skeptical as to whether they're the right tool for the job.

You'll have to build a new dictionary and insert the items in the correct order.

If your question is "how can I sort strings by calendar order," you might find this helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60624571/sort-list-of-month-name-strings-in-ascending-order

You could use an dictionary comprehension with an OrderedDict:
#!/usr/bin/env python

from collections import OrderedDict

old = {2024: {
  'Jul': ['Rate', 'Hours', 'Cost'],
  'Jan': ['Rate', 'Hours', 'Cost'],
  'Feb': ['Rate', 'Hours', 'Cost'],
  'Mar': ['Rate', 'Hours', 'Cost'],
  'Apr': ['Rate', 'Hours', 'Cost'],
  'May': ['Rate', 'Hours', 'Cost'],
  'Jun': ['Rate', 'Hours', 'Cost']}}

year = 2024
ordered_months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul']

new = {year: OrderedDict({month: old[year][month] for month in ordered_months})}

print(new)

% ./so78881244.py
{2024: OrderedDict([('Jan', ['Rate', 'Hours', 'Cost']), ('Feb', ['Rate', 'Hours', 'Cost']), ('Mar', ['Rate', 'Hours', 'Cost']), ('Apr', ['Rate', 'Hours', 'Cost']), ('May', ['Rate', 'Hours', 'Cost']), ('Jun', ['Rate', 'Hours', 'Cost']), ('Jul', ['Rate', 'Hours', 'Cost'])])}

Perhaps keep in mind that objects/dictionaries are inherently unordered, until you manually apply an order on the keys you are reading from.

Thank you Alex !! It worked like a charm.
