# Sort 2D list based on second column

Tags: python, list, sorting, 2d

I am sorting a 2D list in Python. Right now I sorted the list in an ascending order based on the first column. My list look like this:

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5cFk.png)

Now only sort those rows which have the same element at first column, based on second column. And it should look like this:

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1Fve.png)

Comment: I think it's better to post lists in question not as an image

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[Sort a list by multiple attributes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233476/sort-a-list-by-multiple-attributes)*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're asking a combination of these two questions:

1. How to sort a list in Python by multiple attributes: [Sort a list by multiple attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233476/sort-a-list-by-multiple-attributes).
2. How to sort by date in Python: [How do I sort this list in Python, if my date is in a String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589479/how-do-i-sort-this-list-in-python-if-my-date-is-in-a-string)

Hopefully those answers help.