# Sorting a python list based on date?

Tags: python

I have a list of lists where each sub-list contains date values. How can I sort this based on Date?

```
tList=[['xX0001', '10006', '102', '', '2018-02-02', 3233.9, 0.0, 36816.18, ''], 
['xX0001', '10006', '102', '', '2018-02-01', 4142.45, 0.0, 40146.55, ''], 
['xX0001', '10006', '200', '', '2018-02-02', 14367.539999999999, 0.0, 41496.42999999999, ''], 
['xX0001', '10006', '200', '', '2018-02-01', 12663.27, 0.0, 56043.94, '']]
```

Comment: Have you done anything to solve this yourself?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort (list/tuple) of lists/tuples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121979/how-to-sort-list-tuple-of-lists-tuples)

Comment: For that matter, why are you calling those things tuples?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2589479/2988730

Comment: @MadPhysicist Agree with you, (i think you couldn't close this as duplicate because you close this as too broad right?)

Comment: @MadPhysicist Same with me

Comment: @MadPhysicist There's actually no need to convert the date strings to `datetime` objects in both this case and the question you link to because the lexicographical order happens to be the same as the chronological order.

Comment: @blhsing https://stackoverflow.com/a/2589499/2988730

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try, and you will get you expect sort

```
In [51]: a=[['xX0001', '10006', '102', '', '2018-02-02', 3233.9, 0.0, 36816.18, ''], 
    ...: ['xX0001', '10006', '102', '', '2018-02-01', 4142.45, 0.0, 40146.55, ''], 
    ...: ['xX0001', '10006', '200', '', '2018-02-02', 14367.539999999999, 0.0, 41496.42999999999, ''], 
    ...: ['xX0001', '10006', '200', '', '2018-02-01', 12663.27, 0.0, 56043.94, '']]
In [52]: sorted(a, key=lambda b: b[4])
Out[52]: 
[['xX0001', '10006', '102', '', '2018-02-01', 4142.45, 0.0, 40146.55, ''],
 ['xX0001', '10006', '200', '', '2018-02-01', 12663.27, 0.0, 56043.94, ''],
 ['xX0001', '10006', '102', '', '2018-02-02', 3233.9, 0.0, 36816.18, ''],
 ['xX0001',
  '10006',
  '200',
  '',
  '2018-02-02',
  14367.539999999999,
  0.0,
  41496.42999999999,
  '']]

In [53]: sorted(a, key=lambda b: b[4])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
print(sorted(tList,key=lambda x: x[4]))
```

Or:

```
tList.sort(key=lambda x: x[4])
print(tList)
```